# Getting the click on the border of a Shape

Tags: java, shapes

Is there a way to simply check if a mouse click is ON the Shape's border?

I'm actually using the `contains` method but it does not work if the click is made on the Shape border.

Comment: Can you please add some more details? Are you talking about 2D or 3D? What framework/library are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried nothing :-) im using the Shape and Graphics2D. can't find a proper method to do this, and i dont know how to access the border-line (at least, without having tons of work)

Answer (score 2):

Use `BasicStroke`. Define thickness (let's say 5 pixels) and use `yourShape.getStrokedShape().contains(yourPoint)`

Comment: Can you please paste a concrete example?

Comment: I get this error:
The method getStrokedShape() is undefined for the type Shape. I cant use this method of a Shape object

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html#createStrokedShape(java.awt.Shape)